# Detecting whether the camera button has been pressed using J2ME

Tags: java, java-me, camera

I am trying to develop an application in which I want to know when the camera button(if the phone has one),has been pressed for feature phones like Series60 using J2ME.I dont want to take a snapshot or take a video.I just want to know when the hardware  button has been pressed.

I have been unable to find a proper way for this.Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Create a canvas, listen for keypresses and output all events to the screen.  If no event occurs when you press the camera key then you can't do it.